# AWS + Route53 + CWP7 + Sub/Addon Domain Nameserver Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualhost, subdomain, dns-zone, amazon-route53

I am trying to configure the CentOS CWP 7 Control Panel in the same method I used to handle cPanel WHM in the olden days, but I'm running into trouble.

The problem is: How do I configure CWP & Route53 to handle additional (customer sub/addon) domains through CWP without adding more zone entries to Route53? Is it something aboout Virtual Hosts?

I am runnning CWP in Centos 7 on an AWS EC2 instance with an elastic IP.

Nameservers at the registrar for "primary.com" are pointed to Route53.

Route53 has A records for "primary.com" EC2 instance, hostname & PTR.

I have created white label nameservers from the AWS delegation set (ns1.primary.com, ns2 ....)

Internal CWP nameservers are set to: ns1.primary.com > ns1_white_label_IP, ns2.primary.com > ns2_white_label_IP

CWP hostname is server.primary.com.

NAT subnet is checked in CWP Settings.

In CWP, I create a user account for primary.com and when I access primary.com in a browser it works just fine.

However, when I create a user account (or addon) for "secondary.com", the site cannot be reached in the browser. At registrar, "secondary.com" has white label nameservers ns1.primary.com, ns2.primary.com.... Error is something about not authoritative?

What am I missing?

Thank you so much.